# how to append html to the variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have this kind of structure...

```
<div class="copy_from">
        <img src="images/1.png" />
    </div>

    <button class="copy_button">Copy</button>

   <div class="copy_to">
    </div>
```

i want to add the content of the copy_from div to copy_to div with an additional button "Add to Cart".

i am trying this...but it is not working...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.copy_button').click(function () {
                var one1 = $('.copy_from').html();
                var two = $(one1).append('<button>Add to Cart</button>');
                $('.copy_to').html(one1);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/ujj0pw6m/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
   $('.copy_button').click(function () {
          var one1 = $('.copy_from').html() +  '<button>Add to cart</button>';                    
          $('.copy_to').html(one1);
    });
```

Or you could try changing this line

```
 $('.copy_to').html(one1);
```

to ->

```
$('.copy_to').prepend(one1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You've just got the order of things a bit mixed up.  You make a copy of the html from `.copy_from` and then you add the button, afterwards.  You can simply add the button to `.copy_to` afterward instead...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.copy_button').click(function () {
        var one1 = $('.copy_from').html();
        $('.copy_to').html(one1).append('<button>Add to Cart</button>');
    });
});
```